# Can you put a mezuzah on someone else's home without permission?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

Can you put a mezuzah up on someone else's home without permission?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I'm not sure why you would want to do that.

We learn in the Gemara (פסחים ד' ע"א, בבא מציעא ק"א ע"ב, עבודה זרה כ"א ע"א) and it's codified by the Rambam ([Mezuza 5:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2305n.htm)) that `שֶׁהַמְּזוּזָה חוֹבַת הַדָּר הִיא` - the obligation to affix a Mezuza falls on the occupants, and not on the building.

In other words, the person living there has a Mitzva to affix the Mezuza. There's no obligation for the house to have a Mezuza; there's a Mitzva for the inhabitant to affix a Mezuza on their own house.

So you may not be achieving anything - Mitzva wise - by putting a Mezuzah up on someone else's home without permission.

Secondly, there's a problem of damaging other people's property, which is forbidden. So unless you can affix that Mezuza without damaging the doorpost (no holes, no glue, etc.) you are going to be responsible for damages.

BTW: One is also forbidden from causing damage with the intent of paying for the damage.

End result: You may do more harm than good - Mitzva wise - by  putting a Mezuzah up on someone else's home without permission.

Comment: wouldn't this be similar to a situation where a parent refuses to circumcise a child so the beis din or community becomes responsible?

Comment: Also the person may tear it down and disrespect it.

Comment: @user6641 - By Mila the Rambam says ובית דין מצווין למול את אותו הבן או העבד, בזמנו; ולא יניחו ערל לא בישראל, ולא בעבדיהם. but by Mezuza he says  שֶׁהַמְּזוּזָה חוֹבַת הַדָּר הִיא clearly not the same. Besides, Mila is an exception; most Mitzvot we try persuade the person to do it, but don't do it for him. (Maybe because the kid cannot help himself?)

Comment: so you're saying that if the person living there gave permission but didn't outright make the other person a shaliach it would still be no good?

Comment: Also, consider *darchei shalom* if you think the owner would object (e.g. he's an apikorus who thinks you're trying to preach at him; your desire to bring him around wouldn't automatically trump his objections).

Comment: If the person lives in a house, there is most likely some property that you must pass upon before you get to the doorway. Walking on his property without permission violates most local laws, i.e. - tresspassing, and probably a halacha of "massig g'vul".

Comment: @DanF, I doubt it, on both counts: IANAL but I don't think walking on property is trespassing (where I live) unless there's a sign or audible request to not enter, and IANA rabbi but I think walking on someone's property is a case of _kofin al midas S'dom_.

Comment: @user6641 - I don't know; that would depend what is considered "making a Shaliach". At the best of times we didn't expect a Shaliach to make a Kinyan; formal approval would seem to suffice to make the owner involved. But that would make an interesting topic for a Drasha one day. :-)

Comment: Does the concept of "זכין לאדם שלא בפניו" come into play here?

Comment: @IsraelReader - au contraire - you are preventing HIM from doing HIS Mitzva. That's not זוכין as I see it.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I assumed that the question was referring to a case, where the person was obviously neglecting to fulfill his obligation. עי' בס' ברכי נפשי (שמות, בסופו, שו"ת על ס' המצוות הקצר, מצוה יב, אות כט) שאלה: ראובן מזכה את הרבים, רוצה לקבוע על פתח ביתו של שמעון, מבלי שנתבקש, ובטוח ששמעון לא יסיר את המזוזה, האם יברך מבלי שמינהו שליח על כך

Comment: What is the halacha regarding the recitation of a bracha in such a case? "לקבוע מזוזה" או "על קביעת מזוזה". - עי' רמב"ם (הל' ברכות, פי"א, הל' יג) - שו"ת מנחת יצחק (ח"ו, סי' קיב). - אמנם עי' בס' פירושים ופסקים לרבינו אביגדור (פסק רעא) דמשמע מדבריו שהקובע מזוזה לחבירו אינו מברך כלל [ראה שם הערה כח].